# I cannot get correct result for $....<...$ in <li> by MathJax

Tags: html, mathjax

I have many context worked in latex$$, but not each one have space before < and after <.
When I use mathJax to show them, they are not workable in which there is no-space.
Is it a issue or a spec rule?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Mathedemo</title>

        <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
            MathJax.Hub.Config(
                {
                    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'],['$ ', ' $'], ['\\(','\\)']] ,processEscapes: true},
                    "HTML-CSS":
                    {
                        styles:
                        {
                            ".MathJax nobr":
                            {
                                padding: "0.5em 0.5em"
                            },
                        }
                    }
                });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
        </script>


</head>

<body>
<h2> Correct Latex Examlple</h2>
   <ol class="styleqops"> 
    <li> $ p < q < r $ </li>
    <li> $ p < r < q $ </li>
    <li> $ q < p < r $ </li>
    <li> $ q < r < p $ </li>
    <li> $ r < q < p $ </li>
   </ol>
<h2> UNCorrect Latex Examlple</h2>
   <ol class="styleqops"> 
    <li> $p<q<r$ </li>
    <li> $p<r<q$ </li>
    <li> $q<p<r$ </li>
    <li> $q<r<p$ </li>
    <li> $r<q<p$ </li>
   </ol>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the answer below @deryann

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you have to put spaces around the **special characters** which can be used in browser in HTML as well like `<` or `>` etc or you can also use `&lt;` or `&gt;` instead.

**Example**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Mathedemo</title>

            <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
                MathJax.Hub.Config(
                    {
                        tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'],['$ ', ' $'], ['\\(','\\)']]},
                        "HTML-CSS":
                        {
                            styles:
                            {
                                ".MathJax nobr":
                                {
                                    padding: "0.5em 0.5em"
                                },
                            }
                        }
                    });
            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript"
              src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
            </script>


    </head>

    <body>
    <h2> Correct Latex Examlple</h2>
       <ol class="styleqops"> 
        <li> $ p < q < r $ </li>
        <li> $ p < r < q $ </li>
        <li> $ q < p < r $ </li>
        <li> $ q < r < p $ </li>
        <li> $ r < q < p $ </li>
       </ol>
    <h2> UNCorrect Latex Examlple</h2>
       <ol class="styleqops"> 
        <li> $p&lt;q&lt;r$ </li>
        <li> $p&lt;q&lt;r$ </li>
        <li> $p&lt;q&lt;r$ </li>
        <li> $p&lt;q&lt;r$ </li>
        <li> $p&lt;q&lt;r$ </li>
       </ol>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Usually, it is sufficient to simply put spaces around these symbols to cause the browser to avoid them, so

```
... when $x < y$ we have ...
```

**Please follow the documentation here:**
 http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#tex-and-latex-in-html-documents